# Pandas: unpack column in tuple length 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a DataFrame `df` with many column values like so:

```
index   Column1
0       [data1]
1       [data2]
2       [data3]
3       [data4]
4       [data5]
5       [data6]
```

I am looking for a simple Pandas or NumPy command to convert it to a DataFrame like this:

```
index   Column1
0       data1
1       data2
2       data3
3       data4
4       data5
5       data6
```

Currently I am doing:

```
df[Column1] = [each[0] for each in df[Column1]]
```

but this would require me to loop through all the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `str` accessor to get the element out of the list:

```
df['Column1'] = df['Column1'].str[0]
```

For instance:

```
>>> df
   Column1
0  [item1]
1  [item2]
2  [item3]

>>> df['Column1'].str[0]
0    item1
1    item2
2    item3
```

The primary use of `str` is to open up a column or Series to Pandas' vectorised string operations, but it can also be useful if the values in the column are Python lists.